# WebAudio: How to deactivate microphone

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

WebAudio allows to access a microphone via `navigator.getUserMedia()`. When calling this, Browsers show a recoding sign (red dot in Chrome and Edge) that indicates that the microphone is in use. This works fine, but I would like to be able to deactivate the microphone and then this red dot should also disappear. I thougth calling `webcontext.close()` would also deactivate that red dot sign, but it doesnt, at least in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

How do I deactivate a microphone in a way that also browsers recording signs disappear?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to find the solution myself, in case someone is interested:

Imagine we activate our microphone like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
    this._userMediaInputStream = stream;
    ...            
}).catch(errorFunction);
```

Then we can deactivate the microphone using the following piece of code. This will make the browser's recording symbol dissappear too:

```
this._userMediaInputStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => {
    track.stop();
});
```

Comment: To stop all tracks, including video streams from a webcam, use `getTracks` instead of `getAudioTracks`